# How can I pass a variable from a function into the columns.str.replace command?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to pass a string variable into the columns.str.replace, from a function.

Here is the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

df

num_legs    num_wings   num_specimen_seen
falcon  2   2   10
dog     4   0   2
spider  8   0   1
fish    0   0   8
```

This command works, when tested separately from a function:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("num", "SUM")
df
SUM_legs    SUM_wings   SUM_specimen_seen
falcon  2   2   10
dog         4   0   2
spider  8   0   1
fish    0   0   8
```

However, when I try to pass in the variables as part of a function, they do not get recognized as strings.

```
def customize_df(old_column_value,new_column_value):
    df1 = df.copy()
    df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace(old_column_value, 
    new_column_value)
    return df1

customize_df(num,SUM)
```

Error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-16-e645dd7b50f4> in <module>
----> 1 customize_df(num,SUM)
```

NameError: name 'num' is not defined

Comment: change it to `customize_df("num", "SUM")`. Also, return `df1`, not `df`

Comment: thank you! I implemented the df to df1 change in my question for future reference.

Comment: You're still trying to pass undefined variables to your function. Either use strings: `customize_df("num", "SUM")` or define the variables before calling the function.